# Get Type Error: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I try to get data from the database and display that data in the frontend. This is the code that I wrote to do this task.

```
const { id } = useParams();
console.log(id);

const [posts, setPosts] = useState({});

useEffect(()=>{
    getOnePost();
}, []);

useEffect(()=>{
    if (posts && posts.location) {
        console.log(posts.location);
        console.log(posts.location.longitude);
        console.log(posts.location.latitude);
    }
}, [posts]);

const getOnePost = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/buyerGetOnePost/${id}`)
        console.log(response);
        const allPost=response.data.onePost;
        setPosts(allPost);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
    }
}

console.log(posts);
console.log(posts.location.longitude);
console.log(posts.location.latitude);
```

I pass an id to API and get relevant data from the backend.

When I call `console.log(posts)`, it prints the data that get from the backend successfully:

[image: This shows the posts data]

Posts data have a location object. When I try to print location data in the console like this, it also gives the output successfully:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if (posts && posts.location) {
        console.log(posts.location);
        console.log(posts.location.longitude);
        console.log(posts.location.latitude);
    }
}, [posts]);
```

This is the location data:

[image: This is the location data]

But when I try to print the location data like this:

```
console.log(posts.location.longitude);
console.log(posts.location.latitude);
```

I get:

> Type Error: Cannot read property of 'longitude' undefined.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional chaining:

```
posts?.location?.longitude
posts?.location?.latitude
```

Basically, it won't continue if the term before the *?* is falsy. So, it is the same as this:

```
if(posts && posts.location) doSomething(posts.location.longtitude)
```